# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '[module name]'

Tags: pip, python-venv

When I run code importing a module, I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '[module name]'

However, if I run the Python file in the terminal , in a virtual environment, it works.

I am working with:

- Python 3.10.6
- Vscode (version 1.75.1 - Universal)
- venv
- mac os Monterrey

My workflow for starting and working on a project (at the moment is learning exercises as I am a beginner) is the following:

- I create a folder for the project, using mac Finder
- In vscode I open the project folder
- In vscode terminal,  inside the project folder, I create a virtual environment for the project, using:
  python3 -m venv env.[some name]
- I activate the virtual environment with:
  source ./env.[some name]/bin/activate
- Using the command palette, I select the interpreter of the virtual environment i just created
- In the vscode terminal screen, with the activated venv, I install modules using:
  python3 -m pip install [module name]
- Inside the project folder I create the .py files

I don't understand why running the code does not find the module, but running the Python file works.

[I use this dropdown to either run code or run file in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9XHy.png)

Comment: Have you read this yet? It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: Depending on what you use to run your code, python's module detection might work differently

Comment: It could also help if you included the source code. It's best to reduce it to the minimal version of it that still causes the problem

Comment: are you sure that you choose your custom env as a Python interpreter in VS?

Comment: HoangMinhQuangFX15045 - Yes, I verified, and I chose the custom env as the Python interpreter

Arseny - Thisline of code still causes de error: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt